# Is it possible to get rid of fear completely?

Tags: fear

Is it possible to get rid of fear completely.

By fear i do not mean phobias but all kinds of fear whether it is rational(like to fear of getting kill by a tiger) and irrational fear(like phobias).

Comment: No scope of intervention is mentioned, such as *pharmacological*, *behavioural*, or *surgical*. Without scope, the question may be too broad.